# Simple plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am an R novice.

I have been able to get my header-less data into columns:

```
my_data<- separate(my_data,col = "V1",into = c("Date", "Tool","Dept","Port","Host","Min","Max"),sep = ":")
```

It looks like this:

```
          Date   Tool         Dept  Port     Host Min Max
1: 03-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   1   7
2: 10-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   0   7
3: 17-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   1   7
```

I plot it:

```
> p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = Max, x = Date),data = My_data)
> p1
```

But all I get is this:

[image]

How can I plot the min/max over time?

EDIT1:
These are dates, not factors or anything else

EDIT2:
I tried the suggestion:

```
my_data$Date <- as.Date(lmt$Date, "%d-%b-%Y")
```

and got
[image: newest]

Comment: Why don't you add the data argument to `ggplot`?

Comment: Is it not ...,data = my_data) ?  that is my data frame.

Comment: What error if any do you get as your sample data is not enough to make a plot?

Comment: No error.  The data is hundreds of lines so I am experimenting with something small.  The plot is the problem.  It does not show what the max and the min was per day.

Comment: Basically all you need to do is get your data into long form - convert the `min` and `max` columns into one colum, then plot by that column. It is better to specify the data in the `ggplot` call rather than the subsequent calls to `geoms` unless necessary.

Comment: You write `data = My_data` and not `data = my_data`?

Comment: Those are not dates, they are strings (or factors). Just do `My_data$Date <- as.Date(My_data$Date, "%d-%b-%Y")`. And it worked with me.

Comment: As mentioned, I am a novice here:  is My_data$Date <- as.Date(My_data$Date, "%d-%b-%Y") supposed to convert just the column named "date" to a date?  ... and keep the rest of the data?

Comment: I tried it an it appears to work, right?  So now am I looking at a true date?

Comment: How can I also show what was the min for that day?

Comment: It seems there are data type issues, which are hard to help with without having a sample of *actual* data, such as from `dput`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on reproducible R posts

Comment: Here is my raw data:03-Mar-2019:toolset:Headquaters:1234:host.com:1:7
10-Mar-2019:toolset:Headquaters:1234:host.com:0:7
17-Mar-2019:toolset:Headquaters:1234:host.com:1:7

Comment: > dput(head(my_data,4))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17958, 17965, 17972), class = "Date"), 
    Tool = c("toolset", "toolset", "toolset"), Dept = c("Headquaters", 
    "Headquaters", "Headquaters"), Port = c("1234", 
    "1234", "1234"), Host = c("host.com", "host.com", 
    "host.com"), Min = c("1", "0", "1"), Max = c("7", 
    "7", "7")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000000000c371ef0>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your basic plot:

```
My_data<-read.table(header=TRUE,, text="Date   Tool         Dept  Port     Host Min Max
03-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   1   7
10-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   0   7
17-Mar-2019 toolset Headquaters  1234 host.com   1   7")

My_data$Date <- as.Date(My_data$Date, "%d-%b-%Y")

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(data=My_data, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Max), col="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Min), col="green")
print(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  It is close to what I had imagined.  Now I need to find out how to load the real data file full of raw data and automate the process.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with how your datetime is structured at the moment.
you can run an `str(my_data)` to see how your date is formatted. There are many date formats but POSIXct is the best imo. If the date is a factor or anything else, convert it to a character by `as.character()`

After it's converted, you can convert your datetime with `strptime(my_data$Date, %d-%b-%Y)`  Once the date is formatted properly, you can run your ggplot: 
`p1 <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Date, y = Max)) + geom_line()`

I have full details in my tutorial below to help you out in case you need it. Dates can be a little tricky to work with, especially when you have to specify the format argument in `strptime()` ex(%M or %d).  There's a chart on the site that lists all the possible formats.

https://jackylam.io/tutorial/uber-data/

Comment: How is this an answer? Have you tried that code line? In your tutorial there are clues as how to solve the OP's problem, yes, but you should post an answer, not just a link. Link only answers are a reason to flag as VLQ.

Comment: you're right. I'll edit my answer to include edits to datetime.

Comment: Is thie what you were asking?  $ labels     :List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "Date"
  ..$ y: chr "Max"

Comment: your data is in a list? how are you importing your data?

Comment: @Jacky  I have a text file and this is how Ithought I could import:  my_data <-read.table(file="my_data_file.txt",nrows=3, header=F)